# How to debug rspec on Rails5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am looking for help debugging this combo:

Rails 5, rspec-rails, capybara, selenium-webdirver, firefox, and Ubuntu 16.04.

When I try to run a feature spec I see this error:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError:
unable to obtain stable firefox connection in 60 seconds (127.0.0.1:7055)
```

The repo I use to reproduce this bug is listed below:

https://github.com/danbikle/rbug

To reproduce this bug I follow these steps:

```
cd /tmp
git clone https://github.com/danbikle/rbug
cd rbug
bundle install
bin/bundle exec rspec spec/features/firefox_spec.rb
```

I would welcome any clues about how I might debug this bug.

-Dan

bikle101 at gmail

Comment: What version of firefox you use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be in versions of Selenium and Firefox are not compatible,

see [Selenium CHANGELOG](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/CHANGELOG)

Comment: I got Selenium to work via selenium-webdriver gem and chromedriver executable from chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com and the selenium-ruby demo script. Once I saw that work, I made simple configuration changes to rspec in Rails 5. Now I can run feature specs in Chrome. Yay!